# Is there a simpler way to create an array of a certain length using another array as a repeat pattern in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I want to create an app background made of coloured rectangles.

Each rectangle’s colour will be defined by an array of colours of a predefined length.
This array is created by repeating an array serving as a ‘pattern’ until the length defined is reached.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private var colorArray: [Color] = [
        .blue,
        .green,
        .red
    ]
    @State private var newColorArray: [Color] = []
    private var arrayLength: Int = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach((0..<$newColorArray.count), id: \.self) { colorI in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(newColorArray[colorI])
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            newColorArray = newArray(colorArray: colorArray, arrayLength: arrayLength)
        }
    }
    private func newArray(colorArray: [Color], arrayLength: Int) -> [Color] {
        var array: [Color] = []
        
        var colorI = 0
        for _ in 0..<arrayLength {
            if !colorArray.indices.contains(colorI) {
                colorI = 0
            }
            
            array.append(colorArray[colorI])
            
            colorI = colorI + 1
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

What could I change to make it either faster or use less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create the new array. Just use `%` to compute the index into `colorArray`.

This code replaces all of your code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private var colorArray: [Color] = [
        .blue,
        .green,
        .red
    ]

    private var arrayLength: Int = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach((0..<arrayLength), id: \.self) { colorI in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(colorArray[colorI % colorArray.count])
            }
        }
    }
}
```